# Returning an argument pointer to an object

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

In C++ for Windows, I have some object factory that is supposed to create a series of Info object by passing a pointer to the object to a Create function and returning a created object.

```
void CreateInfoObject(AbstractInfo** info);  // The creation function
```

AbstractInfo is a base class of which we have many types of Info objects derive.

I thought I could now create an Info object as follows:

```
MyInfoObject* InfoObj = NULL;  // derived from AbstractInfo object
InfoFactory fc;

fc.CreateInfoObject(&InfoObj); // Now I want to get my initialized pointer back
```

But it says it cannot do the cast...  What is wrong?

ERROR:
    Cannot cast from MyInfoObject**_W64 to AbstractInfo**

EDIT: The first answer mentions that the interface is horrid, cannot see who's allocating etc... How can I improve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's think about a possible implementation of `CreateInfoObject`:

```
void InfoFactory::CreateInfoObject(AbstractInfo** info)
{
  *info = new SuperInfo;
}
```

Now, `SuperInfo` and `MyInfoObject` do not have anything in common right ?

This is why, in general, the following is forbidden:

```
struct Base {};
struct D1: Base {};
struct D2: Base {};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Base** base = nullptr;
  D1* d = nullptr;
  base = d;
}
```

As it would allow `D1` to point to something unrelated.

There are several solutions:

```
// 1. Simple
AbstractInfo* info = nullptr;
fc.CreateInfoObject(info);

// 2. Better interface
std::unique_ptr<AbstractInfo> info = fc.CreateInfoObject();
```

Then, if you know with certainty that you have, in fact, a `MyInfoObject` you can use:

```
MyInfoObject* myInfo = static_cast<MyInfoObject*>(info);
```

or if you are unsure:

```
MyInfoObject* myInfo = dynamic_cast<MyInfoObject*>(info);
```

which will set `myInfo` to `nullptr` if ever the `info` did not pointed to an instance of `MyInfoObject` (or derived).

Bear in mind though, that your interface is really horrid. It very C-ish and it is unclear whether memory is actually allocated or not... and who is responsible for handling it if it is.

**EDIT**:

In *good* C++ style, we use RAII to both denote ownership and ensure clean-up. RAII is well-known though not very indicative, I myself prefer the newish SBRM (Scope Bound Resources Management).

The idea is that instead of using a bare pointer, which does not indicate anything about ownership (ie do you have to call delete on it ?) you should use a **smart pointer**, like for example `unique_ptr`.

You can also make use of the return parameter of the method, to avoid having a two-steps initialization process (first create the pointer, then make it point to an object). Here is a concise example:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<AbstractInfo> AbstractInfoPtr;

// Note: if you know it returns a MyInfoObject
// you might as well return std::unique_ptr<MyInfoObject>
AbstractInfoPtr InfoFactory::CreateInfoObject()
{
  return AbstractInfoPtr(new MyInfoObject());
}

// Usage:
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  InfoFactory factory;
  AbstractInfoPtr info = factory.CreateInfoObject();

  // do something

} // info goes out of scope, calling `delete` on its pointee
```

Here, there is no ambiguity in regard to the ownership.

Also, note how you better understand your question here:

```
  std::unique_ptr<MyInfoObject> info = factory.CreateInfoObject();
```

would not compile because you cannot convert a `AbstractInfo*` to a `MyInfoObject*` without using `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @Tony: I've edited my answer with a proposal for an alternative interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.  Now can I still do a down cast from my retrieved AbstractInfoPtr to a derived object??  Is that a good idea?

Comment: @Tony: yes and no. It's better if your design does not necessitates a downcast, however if you are stuck with a `AbstractInfoPtr` and need a more derived object, then go ahead and downcast. There is no facility (you cannot use `static_cast` directly) so you have to do it manually: 1. get the pointer and cast it, 2. if it succeeds assign it to another `unique_ptr`, 3. release it from the first. In case of a `static_cast`, you can short-cut 2. which gives: `unique_ptr<MyInfoObject> myinfo ( static_cast<MyInfoObject*>(info.release()) );`. For a `dynamic_cast`, this may fail, thus the test before.

Answer (score 3):

Because `CreateInfoObject()` takes a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-an `AbstractInfo`, it's possible for the function to return an instance of `AbstractInfo` that is *not* an instance of `MyInfoObject`. So you could end up with a pointer to `MyInfoObject` that *actually* points to a `DifferentInfoObject`.

Change the `MyInfoObject *InfoObj` to `AbstractInfo *InfoObj` and it should work. Don't cast away the conversion with anything but `dynamic_cast<>` because you don't know for certain that `CreateInfoObject()` returns an instance of that subclass.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler told you what's wrong. You cannot convert a pointer of type T* to a pointer of type U* when T and U have nothing to do with each other. Here, T=MyInfoObject*, U=AbstractInfo* and these are two distinct pointer types that don't share any inheritance relationship.

Comment: The problem isn't pointers. The problem is that `CreateInfoObject()` could return an instance of `AbstractInfo` that is *not* also an instance of `MyInfoObject` and the calling code has no way of ensuring that can't happen.

Comment: To reinforce this answer: even though the classes MyInfoObject and AbstractInfo have an inheritance relationship, the pointer types MyInfoObject* and AbstractInfo* do not.

Comment: @Jonathan: The calling code is invalid anyways. It is invalid because T and U are not reference-related. The compiler doesn't let you do something like that unless you explicitly cast the pointers in which case you may run into the problem you're referring to.

Comment: @Jonathan: sellibitze is correct; this error would happen even if inheritance weren't involved. For example, `void f(void **vp); int *i; f(&i);` is illegal, too, despite a conversion existing between `int*` and `void*`.

Comment: I just want to mention one more thing. Converting a pointer of type Derived* to Base* may involve a pointer adjustment. That's *another* reason why Derived* and Base* are not reference-related even though Derived and Base are reference-related.

Comment: Thinking a bit more about the problem, I think we're saying fundamentally the same thing: that the code is wrong because there's an invalid conversion between types. I only mentioned inheritance because it looked like @Tony was assuming that, because the class types *were* related, the conversion would be both valid and implicit.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to a pointer just isn't as flexible as a pointer to an object. The compiler will strictly enforce the type without regard to the inheritance tree.

The safest way to fix this code is with a double assignment:

```
MyInfoObject* InfoObj = NULL;  // derived from AbstractInfo object 
AbstractInfo* temp = NULL;
InfoFactory fc; 

fc.CreateInfoObject(&temp); 
InfoObj = dynamic_cast<MyInfoObject*>(temp);
```

Comment: The problem would exist even if he were returning an object without using any pointers (e.g. with a method `AbstractInfo InfoFactory::CreateInfoObject();`.) He's trying to cast an abstract class to a concrete subclass thereof, which produces an ill-formed program and won't compile.

Comment: @Jonathan, that problem is exactly why I use `dynamic_cast` in the answer. If the object returned isn't actually a `MyInfoObject`, the cast will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that happens in `CreateInfoObject`.

Lets say there is another subclass of `AbstractInfo`, call `Foo`.

Inside `CreateInfoObject` we create a new `Foo` and assign it to `*info`. (Allowed upcast).

But outside we now have `Foo` inside a `MyInfoObject**` which is wrong.